# What does サラバイ mean?

Tags: usage, slang

I hear the term サラバイ is casual speak sometimes but I have absolutely no idea what it means.

Example:

```
Me : <new information shared to team>
other person: 上記、承知致しました。
other person: サラバイ
```

Comment: さらば+バイバイ, maybe??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer from this link: http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1359689833

Looks like サラバイ=さらば＋バイバイ, both for "bye".

I don't think this is a proper word in a formal business context, but still possible in a business chat that is not so formal.

Comment: The second part of the last sentence is completely incorrect.

Comment: @TokyoNagoya Thanks for the comment. Sometimes we use some expressions which come from movies, animes, and games in our informal business chat (of course in our own team). I don't know exactly about this "サラバイ" but I think its the same kind of thing. Would you please give some explanation?

Comment: I think by "not so formal business chat" he probably is referring to chatter between coworkers who have a friendly relationship rather than big-B "Business"

Comment: Probably it's Internet slang? I've never heard it in real life.